Rails 7.1 ActiveStorage: Couldn't find ActiveStorage::Blob with 'id'=
I have one Rails 7.1 app running in production on Fly.io using ActiveStorage with S3.
The app allows profile creation from Google Oauth flow, so right after the successful authentication for the first time I have the following methods which reads the google oauth image url, request the 2500width resize and then attach the avatar, called from the OmniauthCallbacksController:
def set_avatar_from_auth(auth)
    if auth.dig(:info, :image).present?
      image_url = auth.dig(:info, :image)
      # Replace the size parameter in the URL to request a larger image
      # This example changes the size to 2500x2500 pixels
      large_image_url = image_url.sub(/\bs\d{2,4}-c\b/, 's2500-c')
      attach_image_from_url(large_image_url)
    else
      attach_default_avatar(profile.female?)
    end
  end

  def attach_image_from_url(image_url)
    begin
      profile.create_avatar.image.attach(
        io: URI.open(image_url),
        filename: "#{SecureRandom.hex}.jpg",
        content_type: 'image/jpeg'
      )
    rescue => e
      Rails.logger.error("[User] - Error attaching image por User with id #{id}from URL: #{e.message}")
      attach_default_avatar(profile.female?)
    end
  end

Then I redirect the user to the onboarding page, where at the 3rd step, I have the avatar confirmation/replacement screen:
<%= picture_tag(class: "img-fluid shadow-lg border-0 p-0 align-self-center") do %>
      <%= tag :source, srcset: url_for(current_profile.avatar&.image&.representation(:thumb) || "") %>
      <%= image_tag (current_profile.female? ? 'avatar-girl.png' : 'avatar-boy.png'), alt: current_profile.username, size: '340x340' %>
   <% end %>

Then, not every time but randomly I have this exception:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound active_storage/representations/redirect#show Couldn't find ActiveStorage::Blob with 'id'=xxxx
I suspect there is a race condition but I'm not sure and I can't reproduce on development.

[Update]: I tried moving the attach_image_from_url to a background job but the error had not gone.

My guess is that the blob is somehow deleted between when it's created (when the image is attached) and when the image variant is requested. Maybe a transaction rollback or some active storage cleanup logic.
When you call record.image.representation(:thumb) the blob signed id is used in the generated url, which implies the blob record exists.
But then, in the active storage's representation controller, when it's looked up, roughly something like ActiveStorage::Blob.find_singed!(params[:signed_id), it raises that error. So something happend in between.

I don't see any evidence from the record being deleted in the logs.
